# How can an OBJ sequence be converted to an FBX animation?

Tags: objects, export, unity, .fbx

for a school project, I am trying to import a series of obj models scanned from a Kinnect and import them into blender as sequence of stills, and then after making changes, export them as an FBX to be used in Unity. I have tried using [this stop motion addon](https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ) to import the OBJs as a sequence, but when selecting .fbx when exporting, only a single frame (the first) is ever exported. Is there anything I am able to do to export as an animation?

Comment: Obj doesn't support animations, so every frame has a different object. If you can make a shape key from every object then transform them on one object then you can export it to fbx.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for temporal consistency for 3D scanned objects. Blender won't be able to generate a single mesh that deforms according to the per frame meshes

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee the same number of vertices will appear in the same order in each .obj file (such as a single character model exported to individual frames), you could accomplish this by interpreting the vertex movements mesh transformations on import. Otherwise, you're stuck with entirely separate objects on each frame.

I don't know of any off-the-shelf versions of this, though the stop-motion script you mention in your question could be modified to work this way (in particular, the bakeSequence() function which creates a separate mesh object per-frame).

Comment: Unity is apparently unable to properly import .FBX files with Constant interpolation and/or visibility keyframes. They always come in with Linear interpolation. Because of this, you get weird artifacts in Unity, even if you bake the sequence. As soon as they support Constant interpolation, I have an idea for modifying the `bakeSequence()` function to work nicely with .FBX

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Dem Bones](https://github.com/electronicarts/dem-bones), an open source tool by EA. It creates bones-based animations from multiple frames.

I don't know the process of using it, but it was recently covered in a GameFromScratch video: https://youtu.be/rY7s_2HNw8I